# CrossPlatform Cuepoint Event for HTML5 Video

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, html5-video, flowplayer

*Edittted to ad clarity*

I am looking to create an HTML5 Video playback that triggers events at specific regularly timed cue-points. For example, I'd like an event to fire every second during video playback that checks the contents of a textbox (i.e. at second1 textbox contained; at second2 textbox contained). The 'tricky' part is that I need it to work across all major platforms/browsers, and that includes IPhones and IPads.

**IPhones particularly seem to be a problem** in that no matter the *player, the setting, the hack* I've tried - when a video starts playing, **the browser goes to the background and the video is played in a full-screen container (Quicktime?)**. When the video stops playing and control is back with the browser, I see that the cuepoint events fired, but that's of no use if the textbox is unreachable during video playback!

I am very familiar with FlowPlayer and have already done a bunch of work to ensure it works for playback across most relevant platforms; the cuepoint feature of its API seems to be exactly what we need BUT there's a warning/restriction specific to it:

> *Be aware that cuepoints are subject to device restrictions regarding the HTML5 video API. On devices which do not support inline video
>   because they delegate playback to a system component (e.g. QuickTime
>   on iPhone) the effect of cuepoints is next to none in real world
>   setups*

Has anyone worked with Flowplayer cuepoints OR alternate tech on iPhones/iPads? Obviously, if I can maintain one code base that would be preferrable to having multiple platform-specific versions.

Comment: This is not a problem anymore, since IOS 10 It is possible to play inline videos in iphone. The browser does not change to fullscreen anymore

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple controller for the video element which tracks the timeupdate event fired by the video element to trigger callback functions at the specified timecodes.

It allows you to attach multiple callbacks for the same timecode.

The timeupdate event is fired at different rates on different devices, because of this there is a limitation in that cuepoints can only be attached at integer values so at 5 seconds not 5.5, you can potentially remove this but then there is a risk that the cuepoints will not be triggered

```
/**
 * Function which allows you to register cuepoints to trigger callbacks
 * at specific timecodes
 * @param {HTMLElement} video_el The video element you want to track
 */
var VideoController = function(video_el){
    /**
     * The video element this controller is for
     * @type {HTMLElement}
     */
    this.element = video_el; // 

    /**
     * Object containing all the cuepoints
     * @type {Object}
     */
    this.cuepoints = {};

    /**
     * The last processed_timecode so we dont fire events more than once
     * @type {Number}
     */
    this.processed_timecode = undefined;

    /**
     * Allows you to trigger a callback at a specific timecode
     * @param {Number}   timecode The timecode you want to trigger your callback
     * @param {Function} callback Your callback function
     */
    this.addCuepoint = function(timecode, callback){
        // 
        timecode = Math.floor(timecode);

        //
        if(this.cuepoints[timecode] === undefined){
            this.cuepoints[timecode] = [];
        }

        this.cuepoints[timecode].push(callback);

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to track the videos current timecode and to trigger
     * the cuepoints when neccesary
     * @param  {[type]} e A timeupdate event from the video
     */
    this.timeupdate = function(e){

        var timecode = Math.floor(e.target.currentTime);

        // check to see if there is a callback registered for this timecode
        if(this.cuepoints.hasOwnProperty(timecode) && this.cuepoints[timecode] !== undefined && this.processed_timecode !== timecode){

            //if there is it loops through the array of callbacks and triggers them
            for(var i = 0,l=this.cuepoints[timecode].length;i<l;i++){
                this.cuepoints[timecode][i]();  
            }

        }

        //updates the processed_timecode so we do not fire these callbacks again
        this.processed_timecode = timecode;

    }.bind(this);

    // add addEventListener to the video element to track the video timecode
    this.element.addEventListener('timeupdate', this.timeupdate);

    return this;
}

var video = document.getElementById('myVideoElement');
var video_controller = new VideoController(video);


video_controller.addCuepoint(2,function(){
    console.log('do something at 2 seconds');
});
video_controller.addCuepoint(2,function(){
    console.log('do something else at 2 seconds');
});
```

Comment: I should have been more clear, my apologies. It's not that cuepoints in flowplayer don't work on IPhone, they do - HOWEVER - when a video starts playing in an IPhone browser, it is auto opened in a 'full screen' Quicktime container, so the browser goes to the background.

So let's say you want the cuepoint event to check the state of a button (pressed or unpressed) every second while the video plays, you cannot really achieve it since the button goes to the background... And now that I write this, I see how BADLY misleading my original Q is (arg!)... Editting

Answer (score 1):

I've adapted @Irfan 's answer above to use requestAnimationFrame instead of relying on the timeupdate event.
This will allow for a more granular triggering of events on a half second etc, just adjust the .tofixed(1) as appropriate.
This will not likely help you with the iPhones web video restrictions, but for other use cases it should be helpful to anyone else who needs precise triggering or events based on video time.

```
// Request Animation Frame Shim 
// Source: https://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
            function( callback ){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
            };
})();


var VideoController = function(video_el){
    this.element = video_el; 
    this.cuepoints = {};
    this.processed_timecode = undefined;
    var self = this;
    this.addCuepoint = function(timecode, callback){
        var timecode = timecode.toFixed(1);
        if(this.cuepoints[timecode] === undefined){
            this.cuepoints[timecode] = [];
        }
        this.cuepoints[timecode].push(callback);
        return this;
    }
    this.rafUpdate = function(timestamp){
        var timecode = video_el.currentTime.toFixed(1);
        if(!video_el.duration){
            requestAnimFrame(self.rafUpdate);
        }else if( timecode < video_el.duration ){
            requestAnimFrame(self.rafUpdate);
        }
        if( self.cuepoints.hasOwnProperty(timecode) && self.cuepoints[timecode] !== undefined && self.processed_timecode !== timecode ){
            for(var i = 0,l=self.cuepoints[timecode].length;i<l;i++){
                self.cuepoints[timecode][i]();  
            }
        }
        self.processed_timecode = timecode;
    }
    requestAnimFrame( this.rafUpdate ); // keeps better time than video.timeupdate
    return this;
}


var video = document.getElementById('myvideo');
globalVars['video'] = video; 
var video_controller = new VideoController(globalVars['video']);
video_controller.addCuepoint(10.2,function(){
    endframe.play();
});
```